# OleDbCommand unclosed Datareader Error

Tags: vb.net, oledb

I get a `System.InvalidOperationException` with the additional Info saying that there is an unclosed Datareader in this line.

```vb
MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

`MyCmd` is a Private variable accessible for all subs and is declared as

```vb
MyCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand()
MyCmd.CommandText = "Insert Into Netzwerkverwaltung(NSub, Nip, Npc, Nuser, Pherst, Pser, Pmod, Pcpu, Phdd, Pram, Pkauf, Sos, Sosoem, Sosopen, Sfunk, Soffice, Sofficeoem, Sofficeopen, Anmerkung) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);"
MyCmd.Connection = MyCon
```

After this the parameters are added.

I use `MyCon` in a Sub before with a Datareader but the Datareader is closed when I debug it but it still doesn't work.

```vb
Dim myDR As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
MyCmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Netzwerkverwaltung WHERE ID=?", MyCon)
MyCmd.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("ID", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer))
MyCmd.Parameters("ID").Value = Request("ID")

If MyCon.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
    MyCon.Open()
End If
myDR = MyCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

There I implement the Datareader and close it later on, and it is closed, I double checked that.
This code worked perfectly fine in VS2010 BTW. And I am working with VS2015 right now.

Comment: All your connections, commands, datareaders should be created locally and disposed of when done with them.  Somewhere in your code you left a reader open.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error message telling you that there is a data reader open on that connection then there almost certainly is.  This is why you should always use `Using` blocks for short-lived, disposable objects, e.g.

```
Using myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()
    'Use myDataReader here.'
End Using
```

The reader will be implicitly closed at the `End Using` line so you can't accidentally leave it open.  Depending on specifics, you should probably be doing the same thing with your connection too.

Comment: even when using Using it doesn't work and I still get the same error

Comment: Then either it's a different data reader or something is corrupt on your system or in your project.